# Reduce and create a new array based off 'remaningQuantity'

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, sorting, reduce

I am kind of stuck on how to achieve my desired output.

I just want a bit of help on how should I approach this problem, as I am a junior dev trying to build out a project and I feel that I am overcomplicating things here and still not getting what I want.

The problem:
I have a large array of object, here is a chunk of them:

```
const trades: Trade[] = [
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 50, price: 1800 },
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 20, price: 1850 },
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 25, price: 36800 },
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 5, price: 1900 },
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 10, price: 37000 },
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 40, price: 1700 },
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 25, price: 1750 },
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 15, price: 35000 },
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 5, price: 39000 },
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 5, price: 38500 },
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 80, price: 1350 },
];
```

interfaces:

```js
interface OriginTrade {
  side: 'BUY' | 'SELL';
  asset: string;
  quantity: number;
  remainingQuantity: number;
  linkedTrades: MatchedTrade[];
}

interface MatchedTrade {
  trade: Trade;
  remainingQuantity: number;
  index: number;
}

interface Trade {
  side: 'BUY' | 'SELL';
  asset: string;
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
}
```

The code itself:

```js
const originTrades: OriginTrade[] = trades.reduce<OriginTrade[]>(
  (acc, curr, i) => {
    const { side, asset, quantity } = curr;

    if (!acc[asset]) {

      const originQuantity = side === 'SELL' ? -quantity : quantity; // transform quantity into negative if side is SELL
      acc[asset] = curr;  // If there is no existing origin trade for this asset, set the current trade as the origin trade

      // and push the trades into the array
      acc.push({
        side: side,
        asset: asset,
        quantity: originQuantity,
        linkedTrades: [],
        remainingQuantity: originQuantity,
      });

    } else {

      // if there is an existing previous trade get it and also the side
      // const existingTrade = acc[asset];
      const existingTrade = acc.find((trade) => trade.asset === asset)!;


      // set the math operator based on the side 
      const operator = curr.side === 'BUY' ? '+' : '-';

      // then use that operator to calculate  remaining quantity
      const calculateRemainingQuantity = eval(existingTrade.remainingQuantity + operator + quantity);

      // set the quantity of the current trade based on the side
      curr.quantity = curr.side === 'SELL' ? -curr.quantity : curr.quantity;

      // const existingTradeSide = existingTrade.side;
      existingTrade.linkedTrades.push({ trade: curr, remainingQuantity: calculateRemainingQuantity, index: existingTrade.linkedTrades.length });

      existingTrade.remainingQuantity = calculateRemainingQuantity;

    }

    return acc;
  },
  []
);

console.log('actuall output', originTrades);
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

1. if there is no 'originTrade', then assign the first of its kind a an origin trade
2. in the originTrade for the given asset, add all the upcoming trades into the linkedTrades[], IF the quantity (or balance) is above 0 (therefore we know that the position is not fully closed yet)
3. when goes to 0 or is below 0, then create another 'originTrade' object and assign all the upcoming trades into the linkedTrades[].

What part I am struggling with:

- I have achieved assigning the trades into the initial originTrade and linked all the individual trades into the linkedTrades for that given asset using the reduce, but I am running short on ideas how to achieve that when the remainingQuantity for that given originTrade hits 0 or below 0, then create another originTrade and start linking the trades into that new one.

I feel that I am overcomplicating the code at this point.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Here is the expected output I want to achieve:

```
 [
  {
    "side": "BUY",
    "asset": "ETH",
    "quantity": 50,
    "linkedTrades": [
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "BUY",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": 20,
          "price": 1850
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 70,
        "index": 0
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": -5,
          "price": 1900
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 65,
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": -40,
          "price": 1700
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 25,
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": -25,
          "price": 1750
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 0,
        "index": 3
      }
    ],
    "remainingQuantity": 0
  },
  {
    "side": "SELL",
    "asset": "BTC",
    "quantity": -25,
    "linkedTrades": [
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "BUY",
          "asset": "BTC",
          "quantity": 10,
          "price": 37000
        },
        "remainingQuantity": -15,
        "index": 0
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "BUY",
          "asset": "BTC",
          "quantity": 15,
          "price": 35000
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 0,
        "index": 1
      }
    ],
    "remainingQuantity": 0
  },
  {
    "side": "SELL",
    "asset": "ETH",
    "quantity": -80,
    "linkedTrades": [],
    "remainingQuantity": -80
  },
  {
    "side": "BUY",
    "asset": "BTC",
    "quantity": 5,
    "linkedTrades": [
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "BTC",
          "quantity": -5,
          "price": 38500
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 0,
        "index": 3
      }
    ],
    "remainingQuantity": 0
  }
]
```

And here is the output I am getting now:

```
[
    {
        "side": "BUY",
        "asset": "ETH",
        "quantity": 50,
        "linkedTrades": [
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "BUY",
                    "asset": "ETH",
                    "quantity": 20,
                    "price": 1850
                },
                "remainingQuantity": 70,
                "index": 0
            },
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "SELL",
                    "asset": "ETH",
                    "quantity": -5,
                    "price": 1900
                },
                "remainingQuantity": 65,
                "index": 1
            },
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "SELL",
                    "asset": "ETH",
                    "quantity": -40,
                    "price": 1700
                },
                "remainingQuantity": 25,
                "index": 2
            },
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "SELL",
                    "asset": "ETH",
                    "quantity": -25,
                    "price": 1750
                },
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "index": 3
            },
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "SELL",
                    "asset": "ETH",
                    "quantity": -80,
                    "price": 1350
                },
                "remainingQuantity": -80,
                "index": 4
            }
        ],
        "remainingQuantity": -80
    },
    {
        "side": "SELL",
        "asset": "BTC",
        "quantity": -25,
        "linkedTrades": [
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "BUY",
                    "asset": "BTC",
                    "quantity": 10,
                    "price": 37000
                },
                "remainingQuantity": -15,
                "index": 0
            },
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "BUY",
                    "asset": "BTC",
                    "quantity": 15,
                    "price": 35000
                },
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "index": 1
            },
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "BUY",
                    "asset": "BTC",
                    "quantity": 5,
                    "price": 39000
                },
                "remainingQuantity": 5,
                "index": 2
            },
            {
                "trade": {
                    "side": "SELL",
                    "asset": "BTC",
                    "quantity": -5,
                    "price": 38500
                },
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "index": 3
            }
        ],
        "remainingQuantity": 0
    }
]
```

The whole code

HERE IN TS: # **https://playcode.io/1450531**
Here using JS editor in SO:

```js
const trades = [
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 50, price: 1800 }, // ORIGIN TRADE n1
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 20, price: 1850 }, // LINKED TO ORIGIN TRADE n1
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 25, price: 36800 }, // ORIGIN TRADE n2
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 5, price: 1900 }, // LINKED TO ORIGIN TRADE n1
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 10, price: 37000 }, // LINKED TO ORIGIN TRADE n2
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 40, price: 1700 }, // LINKED TO ORIGIN TRADE n1
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 25, price: 1750 }, // LINKED TO ORIGIN TRADE n1
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 15, price: 35000 }, // LINKED TO ORIGIN TRADE n2
  { side: 'BUY', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 5, price: 39000 }, // ORIGIN TRADE n3 
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'BTC', quantity: 5, price: 38500 },// LINKED TO ORIGIN TRADE n3
  { side: 'SELL', asset: 'ETH', quantity: 80, price: 1350 }, // ORIGIN TRADE n4
];

const originTrades = trades.reduce(
  (acc, curr, i) => {
    const { side, asset, quantity } = curr;

    if (!acc[asset]) {

      const originQuantity = side === 'SELL' ? -quantity : quantity; // transform quantity into negative if side is SELL
      acc[asset] = curr;  // If there is no existing origin trade for this asset, set the current trade as the origin trade

      // and push the trades into the array
      acc.push({
        side: side,
        asset: asset,
        quantity: originQuantity,
        linkedTrades: [],
        remainingQuantity: originQuantity,
      });

    } else {

      // if there is an existing previous trade get it and also the side
      // const existingTrade = acc[asset];
      const existingTrade = acc.find((trade) => trade.asset === asset);


      // set the math operator based on the side 
      const operator = curr.side === 'BUY' ? '+' : '-';

      // then use that operator to calculate  remaining quantity
      const calculateRemainingQuantity = eval(existingTrade.remainingQuantity + operator + quantity);

      // set the quantity of the current trade based on the side
      curr.quantity = curr.side === 'SELL' ? -curr.quantity : curr.quantity;

      // const existingTradeSide = existingTrade.side;
      existingTrade.linkedTrades.push({ trade: curr, remainingQuantity: calculateRemainingQuantity, index: existingTrade.linkedTrades.length });

      existingTrade.remainingQuantity = calculateRemainingQuantity;

    }

    return acc;
  },
  []
);

console.log('actuall output', originTrades);


const expectedOutput = [
  {
    "side": "BUY",
    "asset": "ETH",
    "quantity": 50,
    "linkedTrades": [
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "BUY",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": 20,
          "price": 1850
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 70,
        "index": 0
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": -5,
          "price": 1900
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 65,
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": -40,
          "price": 1700
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 25,
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "ETH",
          "quantity": -25,
          "price": 1750
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 0,
        "index": 3
      }
    ],
    "remainingQuantity": 0
  },
  {
    "side": "SELL",
    "asset": "BTC",
    "quantity": -25,
    "linkedTrades": [
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "BUY",
          "asset": "BTC",
          "quantity": 10,
          "price": 37000
        },
        "remainingQuantity": -15,
        "index": 0
      },
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "BUY",
          "asset": "BTC",
          "quantity": 15,
          "price": 35000
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 0,
        "index": 1
      }
    ],
    "remainingQuantity": 0
  },
  {
    "side": "SELL",
    "asset": "ETH",
    "quantity": -80,
    "linkedTrades": [],
    "remainingQuantity": -80
  },
  {
    "side": "BUY",
    "asset": "BTC",
    "quantity": 5,
    "linkedTrades": [
      {
        "trade": {
          "side": "SELL",
          "asset": "BTC",
          "quantity": -5,
          "price": 38500
        },
        "remainingQuantity": 0,
        "index": 3
      }
    ],
    "remainingQuantity": 0
  }
]

console.log('expected output', expectedOutput);
```

I also added an 'expectedOutput' JSON there at the end and console logged it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses [`findLast()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLast) to check for the presence of an unclosed position. If one is found, its `remainingQuantity` is updated and an element is added to its `linkedTrades`. If none is found, a new `OriginTrade` object is added to the result array:

```
const result: OriginTrade[] = trades.reduce((a: OriginTrade[], v) => {
    const { side, asset, quantity } = v;
    const origin = a.findLast((v) => v.asset === asset
                                  && v.remainingQuantity !== 0);
    const originQuantity = side === 'SELL' ? -quantity : quantity;

    if (origin) {
        origin.remainingQuantity += originQuantity;
        origin.linkedTrades.push({
            trade: v,
            remainingQuantity: origin.remainingQuantity,
            index: origin.linkedTrades.length
        });
    } else {
        a.push({
            side,
            asset,
            quantity,
            remainingQuantity: originQuantity,
            linkedTrades: []
        });
    }

    return a;
}, []);
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJWAc1AFSnAExQG8AoZZAZ2CIC5kByAIQFUBNB5AH0YGUBRADKCGAbnLI4lShDD1KYDCEziKARwCuccMDABPeiA0BbAEbRVyKBGNxQoTAEUtO-YZPmolgDagA1hAEeIQQlPQAsnBgCAAWgcFEANoAuuIAvqSkoJCwiCiR0XFB+ETIZBSKIfQJEJbWtvbKztpgugbIRmYWEqBEAB7uXV6kGVng0PBIyDVlEtR0jKwc3HxCIpZSMnJUig6Wmi1tg56WAA4YSMfdowgA9iAKyJVEYdMlECnIALzIiRLEVBoEHozHYDAANJJpLIQfwcAAJCHIA6udoAVgADJDzsBLsgAIwADgxGOQaXB-0BC1BHEhmxhjDhiMhKNabmQACYscgcXiiZiyRSKAD5sDVsIkfTtswcABhJGso6ctHYi5igDMADZiaTyZTRSCBBK6dDpUyFS42ejVbixfiAJwkwX6oEgpaS01uuUWw7s-Hc3kagDsJN1QrKVLFDCNIhNW1hCJ9qPoABYA2r6PiQ2GXdSYx744zEyzLUqOSqeRmCUGBXrhZG3WC4wyZfKS772viK4H6OrMU66xGDYsm1DC62k1b6N2q+rHQPwyLXeLY2OW0xve3k8gZ7be4T+8768Po2sCy3zVup8hiTa+X2c6lMncHmArKENN5tugsLh3p8fmeUIADprAIDQkAACkguB6B-bAQBqFJIQANwASm+AA+WYKAoF9HiXIhmzAK82jJb5kBQ8QJDw+5HluDAEIouBgJgXpBCkMBoPQrDKOAqVvi+H4BIAMhEvj6jsEAHGaVFkAAQiE5AMTQyxaNfZAGN-EBZKtCjRUEn5TwlZAAH5kAAWkVfRkHoay9Go3DkGAGBkEgrSEIw8onNwjzQFAmwpJk0sbIAah+PydJChyaJ8yLgN8EAAmKEJKGA04NEoGJIO8nyfKA+gUPDPKnMkxonGi+h4rK6Smmi4qSooXoIAGTTGP8xLkpqNLvAgZQwBiWKnLSVTYrSZAIG8GQcJKliMqynKhpK0UGsaqVVpK+yNrymrgo7Kr2qijttp8zr4neV4UiWigRrUslMlK2QNCgEBJHSSEUlG0h8NuXqEtuTBIOsShPzAVSgA)</sup>

Comment: damn this is impressive, never thought of using findLast. I knew that I am doing bit of nonsense in my code as yours is really easy to read and does exactly what it should.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that you need to target ES2023 to be able to use `findLast()`. The same can be trivially achieved using a plain old reverse loop though. Even a regular `find()` would do it, but you might have to traverse a lot of elements before you get to the one you need.

Comment: I already changed my lib to ES2023, I am good with it - I need to achieve the best performance here since this will be processing a lot of data, as one user can have easily 10k trades. 
This will be ran server-side in nextjs on the initial load, then saved to the database and called to client from the database everytime the user visits the site then.

Comment: But again, thank you very much I was already coming up with really difficult hacky solutions and this really helped me to a lot to approach the problem from a different angle.